# How to Deny Global (Require all denied) and Allow Local Access?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I want to deny access globally and allow access to certain IPs and to certain folders (ie. /user). Here is the global setting:

```
<Directory />
    Require all denied
</Directory>
```

Here is the local override (version 1):

```
<Directory /user>
    <RequireAll>
        Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
        Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

Version 2:

```
<Directory /user>
    <RequireAll>
        Require all denied
        Require ip 173.245.48.0/20
        Require ip 103.21.244.0/22
    </RequireAll>
</Directory>
```

My questions are:

1. Like in version 2 do I need to add `Require all denied` again to `/user` folder or not for this to work? If I don't put it, like in version 1, will `Require all denied` be applied from the root folder?
2. If version 1 is correct do I need to use `<RequireAny>` or `<RequireAll>` to group those IP addresses? Note that I want to grant them all access.